# How to calculate the sum number of an array of objects with the same property by using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of object like this: `arrayOfObject = [{id:xxx,price:xxx},{id:xxx,price:xxx},....]`, and I list it as a table by using ng-repeat.

Now for each object, the 'id' could be same. I want to calculate the total number of objects with the same id for every different id and then list the total number in one column. The total number only occurs on every first object with a different id like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this using ng-repeat, or any handy way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question is misleading, sum or count?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

**In Js:**

```
    $scope.getVolumeSum = function(items) {
    return items
    .map(function(x) { return x.Id; })
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
  };
```

**In Html:**

```
    <li ng-repeat="(key, items) in data | groupBy: 'Id'">
      id: {{key}}, name: {{items[0].name}}, volume: {{getVolumeSum(items)}}
    </li>
```

Working [`Sample`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/1a0xuj0x/8/)